# How do I set a field value in an C# Expression tree?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Given:

```
FieldInfo field = <some valid string field on type T>;
ParameterExpression targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "target");
ParameterExpression valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "value");
```

How do I compile a lambda expression to set the field on the "target" parameter to "value"?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**.Net 4.0** : now that there's `Expression.Assign`, this is easy to do:

```
FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField("fieldName");
ParameterExpression targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "target");
ParameterExpression valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "value");

// Expression.Property can be used here as well
MemberExpression fieldExp = Expression.Field(targetExp, field);
BinaryExpression assignExp = Expression.Assign(fieldExp, valueExp);

var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, string>>
    (assignExp, targetExp, valueExp).Compile();

setter(subject, "new value");
```

**.Net 3.5** : you can't,  you'll have to use System.Reflection.Emit instead:

```
class Program
{
    class MyObject
    {
        public int MyField;
    }

    static Action<T,TValue> MakeSetter<T,TValue>(FieldInfo field)
    {
        DynamicMethod m = new DynamicMethod(
            "setter", typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(TValue) }, typeof(Program));
        ILGenerator cg = m.GetILGenerator();

        // arg0.<field> = arg1
        cg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        cg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        cg.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        cg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Action<T,TValue>) m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T,TValue>));
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        FieldInfo f = typeof(MyObject).GetField("MyField");

        Action<MyObject,int> setter = MakeSetter<MyObject,int>(f);

        var obj = new MyObject();
        obj.MyField = 10;

        setter(obj, 42);

        Console.WriteLine(obj.MyField);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great response barry, you answered my initial question.  I'm going to post another question where I need op codes for calling a conversion first....  THANKS!

Comment: Just curious, what is the difference of this approach versus just using System.Reflection and MemberInfos to set the property?

Comment: I'm terribly surprised with your answer +1. nice job!, congrats : )

Comment: Very useful stuff, but beware of edge cases! Value type cases are not handled in this MakeSetter method.

Comment: @Oleg Mihailik: what you meant saying that value types are not handled? If the field is a value type, there is no problem. If the source (T) is a value type, I think no setter can really work as expected.

Comment: @BladeWise yes no setter can work, since structs are always copied. There is workaround though - passing by ref. catch here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272454/generate-dynamic-method-to-set-a-field-of-a-struct-instead-of-using-reflection

Comment: It seems like in the .Net 4 version you can skip getting FieldInfo and pass "fieldName" like this `MemberExpression fieldExp = Expression.Field(targetExp, "fieldName");`

Answer (score 24):

Setting a field is, as already discussed, problematic. You can can (in 3.5) a single method, such as a property-setter - but only indirectly. This gets much easier in 4.0, as discussed [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/future-expressions.html). However, if you actually have properties (not fields), you can do a lot simply with `Delegate.CreateDelegate`:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").GetSetMethod();
        Action<Foo, int> setter = (Action<Foo, int>)
            Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Foo, int>), method);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        setter(foo, 12);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to hear why that got down-voted... seems a pretty decent side-point to me; only applies to properties, but avoids the need for either Reflection.Emit or Expression...

Comment: in the given link, an `Expression.AssignProperty` is mentioned. What is that?

Comment: @nawful in 4.0 trees are much richer, allowing full code blocks. However most linq providers, and the compiler,  don't let you do that. I assume it assigns via a property ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell could you tag my name properly so that I'm alerted. Oh ok, but where did you find this `Expression.AssignProperty` from? Some documentation or link?

Comment: @nawfal sorry for the typo; if you read that post, it says it is based on the 4.0 CTP - i.e. a pre-release build of .NET 4.0; presumably this changed to .Assign in the RTM release.

Answer (score 6):

```
private static Action<object, object> CreateSetAccessor(FieldInfo field)
    {
        DynamicMethod setMethod = new DynamicMethod(field.Name, typeof(void), new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) });
        ILGenerator generator = setMethod.GetILGenerator();
        LocalBuilder local = generator.DeclareLocal(field.DeclaringType);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        if (field.DeclaringType.IsValueType)
        {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, field.DeclaringType);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0, local);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, local);
        }
        else
        {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, field.DeclaringType);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0, local);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0, local);
        }
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        if (field.FieldType.IsValueType)
        {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, field.FieldType);
        }
        else
        {
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, field.FieldType);
        }
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Action<object, object>)setMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, object>));
    }
```

Comment: It seems like the `FieldInfo.DeclaringType` must be public in order for this to work. Otherwise it fails with a `TypeLoadException` in .NET 3.5 and `TypeAccessException` in .NET 4.0/4.5 (although `Expression.Assign` is available in 4.0+, so more of a problem for 3.5).

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. Just had to set the `restrictedSkipVisibility` in the `DynamicMethod` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a way to set properties and fields with Expression Trees in .NET 3.5. It is may be the only option for some PCL profiles that do not support `Delegate.CreateDelegate` (besides the *Reflection.Emit*):

- For field the trick is passing field as *ref* parameter,
  e.g. `SetField(ref holder.Field, "NewValue");`
- The property (as already pointed by Marc) can be set by reflecting and calling its setter method.

The full proof of concept is provided below as NUnit test fixture.

```
[TestFixture]
public class CanSetPropAndFieldWithExpressionTreeInNet35
{
    class Holder
    {
        public int Field;
        public string Prop { get; set; }
    }

    public static class FieldAndPropSetter
    {
        public static T SetField<T, TField>(T holder, ref TField field, TField value)
        {
            field = value;
            return holder;
        }

        public static T SetProp<T>(T holder, Action<T> setProp)
        {
            setProp(holder);
            return holder;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_set_field_with_expression_tree_in_Net35()
    {
        // Shows how expression could look like:
        Func<Holder, Holder> setHolderField = h => FieldAndPropSetter.SetField(h, ref h.Field, 111);
        var holder = new Holder();
        holder = setHolderField(holder);
        Assert.AreEqual(111, holder.Field);

        var holderType = typeof(Holder);
        var field = holderType.GetField("Field");
        var fieldSetterMethod =
            typeof(FieldAndPropSetter).GetMethod("SetField")
            .MakeGenericMethod(holderType, field.FieldType);

        var holderParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(holderType, "h");
        var fieldAccessExpr = Expression.Field(holderParamExpr, field);

        // Result expression looks like: h => FieldAndPropSetter.SetField(h, ref h.Field, 222)
        var setHolderFieldExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Holder, Holder>>(
            Expression.Call(fieldSetterMethod, holderParamExpr, fieldAccessExpr, Expression.Constant(222)),
            holderParamExpr);

        var setHolderFieldGenerated = setHolderFieldExpr.Compile();
        holder = setHolderFieldGenerated(holder);
        Assert.AreEqual(222, holder.Field);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_set_property_with_expression_tree_in_Net35()
    {
        // Shows how expression could look like:
        Func<Holder, Holder> setHolderProp = h => FieldAndPropSetter.SetProp(h, _ => _.Prop = "ABC");
        var holder = new Holder();
        holder = setHolderProp(holder);
        Assert.AreEqual("ABC", holder.Prop);

        var holderType = typeof(Holder);
        var prop = holderType.GetProperty("Prop");
        var propSet = prop.GetSetMethod();

        var holderParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(holderType, "h");
        var callSetPropExpr = Expression.Call(holderParamExpr, propSet, Expression.Constant("XXX"));
        var setPropActionExpr = Expression.Lambda(callSetPropExpr, holderParamExpr);

        var propSetterMethod = typeof(FieldAndPropSetter).GetMethod("SetProp").MakeGenericMethod(holderType);

        // Result expression looks like: h => FieldAndPropSetter.SetProp(h, _ => _.Prop = "XXX")
        var setHolderPropExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Holder, Holder>>(
            Expression.Call(propSetterMethod, holderParamExpr, setPropActionExpr),
            holderParamExpr);

        var setHolderPropGenerated = setHolderPropExpr.Compile();
        holder = setHolderPropGenerated(holder);
        Assert.AreEqual("XXX", holder.Prop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I once made this class. Perhaps it helps:

```
public class GetterSetter<EntityType,propType>
{
    private readonly Func<EntityType, propType> getter;
    private readonly Action<EntityType, propType> setter;
    private readonly string propertyName;
    private readonly Expression<Func<EntityType, propType>> propertyNameExpression;

    public EntityType Entity { get; set; }

    public GetterSetter(EntityType entity, Expression<Func<EntityType, propType>> property_NameExpression)
    {
        Entity = entity;
        propertyName = GetPropertyName(property_NameExpression);
        propertyNameExpression = property_NameExpression;
        //Create Getter
        getter = propertyNameExpression.Compile();
        // Create Setter()
        MethodInfo method = typeof (EntityType).GetProperty(propertyName).GetSetMethod();
        setter = (Action<EntityType, propType>)
                 Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<EntityType, propType>), method);
    }


    public propType Value
    {
        get
        {
            return getter(Entity);
        }
        set
        {
            setter(Entity, value);
        }
    }

    protected string GetPropertyName(LambdaExpression _propertyNameExpression)
    {
        var lambda = _propertyNameExpression as LambdaExpression;
        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = lambda.Body as UnaryExpression;
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        }
        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        return propertyInfo.Name;
    }
```

test:

```
var gs = new GetterSetter<OnOffElement,bool>(new OnOffElement(), item => item.IsOn);
        gs.Value = true;
        var result = gs.Value;
```

Comment: Not answering the question. Its about `FieldInfo`

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness here is the getter:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, object>> GetTypeGetters<T>()
    {
        var fields = typeof (T).GetFields();

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            ParameterExpression targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "target");
            UnaryExpression boxedFieldExp = Expression.Convert(Expression.Field(targetExp, field), typeof(object));
            yield return  Expression.Lambda<Func<T,object>>(boxedFieldExp, targetExp).Compile();
        }
    }
```