# A function to "package" up an object's field member in an Action or Func

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, delegates

How would I "package" an instances field in a func or action by method?

What other possibilities are there for keeping references to a specific (value or reference) field in another class? (I know I can just keep a reference to the object itself)

The following is pseudo-code and will not compile.

```
class TestClass
{

    private static bool someField;

    private Func<bool> FuncPackage (ref bool field)
    {
        return () => ( return field; );
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithPackage (Func<bool> package)
    {
        if(package())
            Console.WriteLine ("true");
        else
            Console.WriteLine ("false");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        someField = false;
        Func<bool> package = FuncPackage (ref someField);
        DoSomethingWithPackage (package);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why simple `()=> this.someField;` does not work? Or equivalent with reflection/[expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321650/how-do-i-set-a-field-value-in-an-c-sharp-expression-tree)?

Comment: What problem you're trying to solve with this? There might be a better way

Comment: I wanted to keep a reference to a field to query later, obviously I could just keep a reference to the object (and with interfaces I could standardize against a property).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i wanted to pass in a field from any other object not just this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is inherently impossible.

You're asking to create a [closure class](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html) that captures a *reference* to the field from the original class.

C# can't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the post!

Comment: @user2994682: For more info, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx